# Postgres - join generate_series to an existing dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
'item': 'test', 'assignee_id': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 1), 'hours_worked': 1
'item': 'test', 'assignee_id': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 4), 'hours_worked': 2
'item': 'test', 'assignee_id': 2, 'date': datetime.date(2023, 3, 2), 'hours_worked': 2
```

As you can see, there is hours worked on a particular day for a particular person, but this data set is missing the empty space of days that aren't included in this data set (2023/03/02, 2023/03/02) for assignee 1.

I'd like to split this across both the days but also the assignee and the item.

I've been able to generate a series of dates using the generate_series function:

```
SELECT t.day::date 
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2023-01-01'
                     , timestamp '2004-02-01'
                     , interval  '1 day') AS t(day);
```

but I don't know how to join these 2 datasets together. Is there an  operation I could use to join across multiple things?

Comment: Nothing in PostgreSQL itself looks like `datetime.date(2023, 3, 1)`.  That appears to be something the client would do, but you didn't indicate your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the result of the `generate_series()` within a CTE. This builds a *localized* view. Once built then then use as any other table or view. For example:

```
with cal(day) as 
     ( select t.day::date 
         from generate_series(timestamp '2023-01-01'
             , timestamp '2004-02-01'
             , interval  '1 day') as t(day) 
     ) 
select * 
  from cal 
  left join sometable 
    on cal.day = sometable.some_date_col;
```

You can just directly `generate_series()` as a sub-query to the table:

```
select * 
  from (select t.day::date 
         from generate_series(timestamp '2023-01-01'
             , timestamp '2004-02-01'
             , interval  '1 day') as t(day)
       ) col
  left join sometable 
    on cal.day = sometable.some_date_col;
```

I typically prefer the first, but that is strictly a personal choice. I think it reads easier and easier to see what is happening, But that is strictly a choice.